# undefined reference to `FIPS_mode'

Tags: openssl, fips

I'm using the FIPS 140-2 module with OpenSSL (https://openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf). I'm programming an application that only gets the FIPS mode.

Here is my Makefile:

```
TOOLCHAIN:=/home/marcos/work/nitere/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin:$PATH
CROSS_COMPILE:=arm-linux-gnueabihf-

OPENSSLDIR = /usr/local/ssl
INCLUDES = -I$(OPENSSLDIR)/include -I$(OPENSSLDIR)/fips-2.0/include
LIBS= -lcrypto

PATH:=${TOOLCHAIN}:${PATH}

all:
    ${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc fipsctl.c -o fipsctl $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -Rf *.o fipsctl
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <stdio.h>

...
int mode = FIPS_mode();
if(mode == 0)
{
    printf("*** FIPS module is disabled. ***");
}
if(mode == 1)
{
    printf("*** FIPS module is enabled. ***");
}
```

When I try to cross-compile, I get this error:

```
marcos@marcos-X450LD:~/work/nitere/app/nitere$ make
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc fipsctl.c -o fipsctl -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/include -Lcrypto
/tmp/ccSQhRme.o: In function main': fipsctl.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `FIPS_mode
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Any tip will be very helpful,
Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need build/install the FIPS Object Module. That's the ***`*-fips-*`*** download. For example, [openssl-fips-2.0.11.tar.gz](https://www.openssl.org/source/).

Comment: Your makefile shows `-lcrypto` lowercase-ell but your log shows `-Lcrypto` uppercase-ell; which is it? If you actually have uppercase in your makefile, that's wrong. @jww: apps don't call the FIPS module directly, only through the 'FIPS capable' OpenSSL library. If `FIPS_mode` did link but on execution returned false, that could be a missing FIPS module.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I installed the FIPS object module and OpenSSL using ./config fips. Did I forget to include some parameter? Is there a way to check if my OpenSSL installation supports FIPS 140-2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I installed the FIPS module correctly. I followed these commands:

Installing FIPS:

```
root@arm:~# cd
root@arm:~# cd openssl-fips-2.0.10
root@arm:~# ./config
root@arm:~# make
root@arm:~# make install
```

Installing OpenSSL with FIPS support:

```
root@arm:~# cd 
root@arm:~# wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2e.tar.gz
root@arm:~# tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2e.tar.gz
root@arm:~# cd openssl-1.0.2e
root@arm:~# ./config fips 
root@arm:~# make depend
root@arm:~# make 
root@arm:~# make install
```

Is it correct?

Comment: That should do it. It's what [Chapter _4.2 Building and Installing the FIPS Object Module with OpenSSL
(Unix/Linux)_](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf) instructs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the FIPS ecp distribution, if yes
Try using no-ec2m option, while compiling openssl, like below:

root@arm:~# cd openssl-1.0.2e
root@arm:~# ./config fips no-ec2m

In the UserGuide2.pdf also it is mentioned as:
"Note that when using the "ecp" distributions the corresponding "FIPS capable" OpenSSL must be built with the noec2m option."